# List of correlations DataFrame Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this table:

```
import pandas as pd
a=pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,2,2,2],[4,2,4,3],[5,1,2,4]],
               columns=(['a','b','c','d'])) `
```

I want to create a table with correlations, but only with those which have a correlation of more then `0.4`.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you need [`corr`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) with [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
print (a.corr())
          a         b         c         d
a  1.000000  0.000000  0.577350  0.970725
b  0.000000  1.000000  0.583333 -0.080064
c  0.577350  0.583333  1.000000  0.520416
d  0.970725 -0.080064  0.520416  1.000000

b = a.corr()
#replace <= 0.4 to NaN
print (b.where(b > 0.4))
          a         b         c         d
a  1.000000       NaN  0.577350  0.970725
b       NaN  1.000000  0.583333       NaN
c  0.577350  0.583333  1.000000  0.520416
d  0.970725       NaN  0.520416  1.000000

#replace <= 0.4 to 0    
print (b.where(b > 0.4, 0))
          a         b         c         d
a  1.000000  0.000000  0.577350  0.970725
b  0.000000  1.000000  0.583333  0.000000
c  0.577350  0.583333  1.000000  0.520416
d  0.970725  0.000000  0.520416  1.000000
```

Comment: I wanna matrix with correletions >4

Comment: I dont understand, here is max correlation only 1. Can you explain more?

Comment: sorry , i mean 0.4.

Comment: so only change `>` to `<`